# Using Visual Composer in Wordpress; raw js not being applied to my raw html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

Here is the code that works on my browser which I am trying to apply to my WordPress page:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<!-- Get jQuery -->    
<script 
src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script src="js/typed.js"></script>

<script>
$(function(){

    $("#typed").typed({
        // strings: ["We are creative.", "We are hard-working.", "We 
are collaborative.", "Try it out!"],
        stringsElement: $('#typed-strings'),
        typeSpeed: 50,
        backDelay: 600,
        loop: true,
        contentType: 'text', // or text
        // defaults to false for infinite loop
        loopCount: false,
        callback: function(){ foo(); },
        resetCallback: function() { newTyped(); }
    });

    $(".reset").click(function(){
        $("#typed").typed('reset');
    });

});

function newTyped(){ /* A new typed object */ }

function foo(){ console.log("Callback"); }

</script>
</head>
<body>
        <div id="typed-strings">
            <p>We are creative.</p>
            <p>We are collaborative.</p>
            <p>We are connected.</p>
            <p>We are Clarke.</p>
        </div>
        <span id="typed">We are</span>   
<style type="text/css">
body {
font-size: 80px;
color: blue;
}
</style>
</body>
</html>
```

When I break this code apart into js and html for wordpress (I put js into the Raw JS option in the visual composer, and html into Raw HTML), none of it works.

Can someone tell me why? Thanks

Comment: Check your console log for any errors. Is the typed library being loaded?

Comment: How do I check in Wordpress for console log errors?
Also see below for how I split up the code and put it into Raw JS and Raw HTML seperarely, I might have done something wrong there

Answer (score 3):

This is because Wordpress uses jQuery in no conflict mode. Replace all the `$` in your js code with `jQuery`. For example :

```
 $(".reset").click(function(){
        $("#typed").typed('reset');
  });
```

should be

```
jQuery(".reset").click(function(){
    jQuery("#typed").typed('reset');
});
```

Comment: Please see my next post below; I've done that but it still does not work, and I don't know where I'm going wrong but it's when I put the JS and HTML seperately into Wordpress. Can you read through the code I posted below and see what I am doing wrong? Ah I am so confused, thank you!

Comment: Take a look at [Chrome's dev console](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console)

I suspect that your type library isn't loading. Try putting an absolute path instead of `/js/typed.js` that will at least confirm if that is the problem. After that you can figure out what the proper relative path is.

Answer (score 2):

You should put your script after the element that your refer at the script. HTML elements must be done loading before script does.